# JQuery Ajax is sending GET instead of POST

Tags: jquery, ajax

The following code triggers a GET instead of a POST HTTP request.

```
function AddToDatabase() {
  this.url = './api/add';
}

AddToDatabase.prototype.postData = function(dataToPost) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: this.url,
    data: dataToPost,
    context: this,
    success: this.onSuccess
  });
};


var AddToDatabase = new AddToDatabase();
data = {data: 'coucou'};
AddToDatabase.postData(data);
```

Why, and how can I get a POST ?

---

I see in Google Chrome Inspect and Firefox Inspect that the browser sends a GET. Here is from Chrome:

> Request URL:http://localhost/SAMPLE-CODES/UPDATE%20MYSQL/api/add/
>   Request Method:GET Status Code:200 OK

---

**SOLVED**

The URL called './api/add' was to actually post to './api/add/index.php'. Turns out that calling './api/add`/index.php`' or './api/add`/`' gives me a POST request.

It was just a wrong URL, but for some reason I was getting a successful GET request to '.api/add/'.

Comment: Why do you think it will be a GET request?

Comment: Have you tried to run the ajax call on firefox with net panel opened on firebug?

Comment: [Test](http://jsfiddle.net/4gh7M/) - if you will run this and check network panel, you will find that it sends a post request

Comment: @FAngel I see in Google Chrome Inspect the following: "Request URL:http://localhost/SAMPLE-CODES/UPDATE%20MYSQL/api/add/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK"

Comment: @tucson what is jQuery version? And - is that the only request there? Maybe you have some redirect inside your /api/add?

Comment: @FAngel the URL called './api/add' is to actually get './api/add/index.php'. Turns out that calling this file directly gives me a POST request.

Comment: @FAngel Thanks for the JSFiddle. FYI I can reproduce on localhost and I get: a POST if there is no folder '/api/add/', and a GET if there is a folder '/api/add/'.

Comment: @tucson - as I already  wrote - check your .htaccess file. Possibly it makes redirect instead of rewrite. Basically, I see that JS is Ok (expect that dot in url './api/add' which confuses me). So it looks more like serverside issue. And information in your question is not enough to give specific help

Comment: Add the solution as the answer please

Comment: thanks for posting your solution - including the file name in the URL instead of relying on the server to redirect to index.php... it's subtle nuances like this that keep my job... interesting... yeah, I'll go with "interesting"

Comment: Hi @tucson :) Its been 5 years overdue to select an accepted answer :D heheh

Answer (score 113):

Some problem on MVC. For some reason when I remove the [HttPost] it works as expected, even though I am telling ajax to use POST .

- It turns out you need to use

> type: "POST"

- Even though the example on jQuery page says to use

> method : "POST"

Now it POST's

But after digging in the documentation I found this.

[image]

Comment: this is the issue I was JUST having. didn't realize that the option name got changed at 1.9. Thought it was always "method"

Comment: I see no problem with including both just to be sure.  `{ method : "POST", type: "POST" }`

Comment: Yea you can include whatever you want in the constructor, but including both of these for compatibility doesn't really make sense. Most people will be using 1.11 or 2.1 by now any way. This just causes a problem after upgrading like from 1.4.3 or 1.6.2

Comment: I spent so long trying to fix this on Friday updating an old frontend to use a brand new API. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 35):

I had this issue and per @FAngle's suggestion it was because my .htaccess was removing trailing slashes — and I had set the url to `/ajax/foo/bar/` and not`/ajax/foo/bar`. The redirect changes the request from POST to GET. Remove the / and problem solved!

Comment: This solved the exact problem mentioned in original question for me. I'm hosting a laravel app on Wamp 3.0.6

Comment: this saved my life. almost 4 hrs debug.

Comment: solved the problem.

Answer (score 11):

The URL `'./api/add'` actually got redirected to `'./api/add/index.php'`. therefore this bizarre side-affect which the new request after the redirect sent using `GET` instead of `POST`

**Solution**

- use the full url `'./api/add/index.php'`
- or add a slash `'./api/add/'` .

Answer (score 8):

I found that when using `dataType: 'jsonp'` it converts the request to a `GET`. I changed it to `dataType: 'json'` it changed from `GET` to `POST`.

Comment: Do you the reason why this behavior was observed ?

Comment: @SaurabhSarathe — JSONP works by generating script elements which can only generate GET requests.

Answer (score 7):

I noticed this behavior as well where my POST was sending a GET.  The scenario's pretty unique, but maybe it will help someone.

This was happening to me on my User Role-edit page, where I was using ajax (post) as an immediate action when a role was checked or unchecked.

I also had the server configured to re-authenticate the user (and redirect them) whenever their role information changed so that their claims would be refreshed.

The brutal cycle ended up as:

1. First Role Update -- POST -- 200 success
2. Next Role Update -- POST -- 302 Found -> Redirect *(I did not
   notice this until I used Fiddler rather than Chrome's network
   monitor)*
3. Redirect Call from (2) (Same URL) -- GET -- 404 Not Found (since
   I only allowed Post)
4. GOTO (1)

I ended up changing the server to bypass re-authentication/claims update when it detected an ajax request (based on the Accept Types).

Comment: Woah! Faced something similar. Apparently, in my controller level, it was expecting a session parameter which I've not included in the new controller endpoint, and it was doing a 302 and then a GET. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 3):

Check out your .htaccess file or search for some other thing that may redirect your request

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and it started working for me as soon as I removed the hardcoded `https://` from my url.

```
jQuery.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "www.someurl.com",//instead of "https://www.someurl.com"
 data: { foo:"bar"},
 success: function(d){ console.log(d); },
 dataType: "JSONP"
});
```

Comment: This sounds more like a problem between HTTP and HTTPS (i.e. your www.someurl.com does not have a valid certificate)

Answer (score 2):

For me, your piece of code look OK, but if you want to be sure, you can use $.post instead of $.ajax

```
$.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
 $('.result').html(data);
});
```

jquery link : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: `post` is just a shorthand method for $.ajax({type:'POST'})

Comment: Yes, but as your code look good. when i'm testing it, it's does some post request

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found this question but answers didn't solve my problem. I eventually solve it by removing `contentType` field in ajax request.

```
contentType: "application/json",
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, and it turned out to be a URL Rewrite module in IIS.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and WebAPI. I created rule to force lowercase URLs so social networks don't view the same URL as two different pages.

For example:

"http://url.com/View/Something/123GuidIdSomething"

vs

"http://url.com/view/something/123guididsomething"

This however, was somehow messing with my ajax requests. I disabled the rule and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

a very common mistake is that we are using button type as submit and not changing the method for form (which is get by default)

make sure you don't use button type submit and if you do you have changed the form method to post

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it turns out that the problem wasn't in the AJAX request.

I had attached `submit` into the `type` attribute of my `input` button, so, when the form was submitted, it was by default a GET request to the `/` path.

Eventually, I replaced the `type` attribute by `button` and it worked.

```js
$.ajax({
          url: "login.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: $("#form").serialize(),
          success: (param) => {},
          error: (param) => {} 
 })
```

```html
<form id="form">
    <label for="foo">Foo</label>
    <input type="text" name="foo" id="foo">
    <br>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    <br>
    <input <!--type="submit"--> type="button" value="Send" id="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue and the problem seemed to be with encoding of the url parameters taken from inputs. Chrome's dev tools where still showing a `POST` request, but the values were being received as a `GET` request.

The code giving problems was:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ajax/test.php?firstname=' + $('#fname').val()+ "&lastname=" + $('#lname').val()+ "&email=" + $('#email').val(),
    success: function(msg) {

        alert("Success");          
    },
    error: function() {

        alert("Failure");
    }
});
```

And the fix was to move the to use the `data` parameter instead of putting the values into the url:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ajax/test.php',
    data: {firstname: $('#fname').val(), lastname: 
    $('#lname').val(), email: $('#email').val()},
    success: function(msg) {

        alert("Success");
                            
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Failure");
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have altered your .htaccess file to remove url file extensions like .php .html etc, AND your jQuery AJAX code looks something like this:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/scripts/assoc/add_new_password.php",
                data: {
                    verification_code: new_psw,
                    script_access: 1
                },
```

You will need to remove the .php part of the url details, like this:

```
url: "/scripts/add_new_password",
```

Another posibility is if you have used a form and have coded the button in this way, with a 'button' tag:

```
<button type="button" id="new_password_submit_button" class="">Submit</button>
```

It should be an 'input' tag:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="new_password_submit_button">
```