# jQuery $.post turning into GET request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have this bit of HTML:

```
<form action="http://shoutzor.nl/login" method="POST" id="loginform" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Have an account? Login!</legend>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="password" name="password" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Login" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<form action="http://shoutzor.nl/login" method="POST" id="registerform"
class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Create an account</legend>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="username" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="email" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Register" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and I've got this bit of JavaScript:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("body").toggleLoadMaskOverlay();

    if ($(this).is("#registerform")) {
        //Registreren
        $.post("http://shoutzor.nl/register ", {
            username: $("#registerform input[name=username]").val(),
            email: $("#registerform input[name=email]").val()
        }, function (result) {
            $("body").toggleLoadMaskOverlay();
        }, "json");
    } else {
        $.post("http://shoutzor.nl/login", {
            test: "test",
            username: $("#loginform input[name=username]").val(),
            password: $("#loginform input[name=password]").val()
        }, function (result) {
            $("body").toggleLoadMaskOverlay();
        }, "html");
    }
});
```

On the server-side I have my own PHP API but this doesn't matter because strangely enough even at the top of the index.php file `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` returns "GET" and `var_dump($_REQUEST)` returns no data at all.

I haven't encountered this problem on any of my other websites (which are using the same PHP CMS I've developed) before so I assume for now I'm doing something wrong in my JavaScript code, but I can't discover the problem.

Comment: Possibly related to this at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195883/jquery-ajax-is-sending-get-instead-of-post?

Comment: @j08691 interesting - from that link, I think it could be how the server is redirecting the request to /login or /register

Comment: @j08691 I feel really stupid right now, that did indeed solve my problem! thank you!

Comment: Nah, don't feel stupid, it was a tricky one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My .htaccess indeed rewrote all urls to end with a '/', because I did requests to http://shoutzor.nl/login (without the ending '/') it became a redirect which I didn't notice.

Adding the '/' solved the problem