# AJAX Call Return PHP Value Empty

Tags: php, ajax, datatables

i have a problem about ajax call, i dont get what exactly why i still getting this empty success call. i tried the past solution to solve this but i don't know what the cause of this.

as you can see this my table then when i click the action of update, delete, or, add, even print_r($_POST) it's still empty.
[image]
[image]
then when i go to console i got this error.
 [image]
 the value of selected attr still send to the php file

heres my code :

```
 $(document).on('click', '.update', function(){
    var user_ID = $(this).attr('id');

$.ajax({
  url:"datatable/account/fetch_single.php",
  method:"POST",
  data:{user_ID:user_ID},
  dataType:"json",
  success:function(data)
  {
    console.log(data);

    $('#account_modal').modal('show');
    $('#username').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#username').val(data.user_Name);
    $('#email').val(data.user_Email);
    $('#pass').val(data.user_Pass);
    $('#con_pass').val(data.user_Pass);
    $('#level').val(data.level_ID).change();
    $('#status').val(data.user_status).change();
    $('#action').val('Edit');
    $('#operation').val('Edit');
    $('.modal-title').text('Edit Account Info');
    $('#user_ID').val(user_ID);
  }
})
  });
```

fetch_single.php

```
include('db.php');
include('function.php');
if(isset($_POST["user_ID"]))
{
    $output = array();
    $statement = $conn->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM `user_accounts`
        WHERE user_ID = '".$_POST["user_ID"]."' 
        LIMIT 1"
    );
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row)
    {

        $output["level_ID"] = $row["level_ID"];
        $output["user_Name"] = $row["user_Name"];
        $output["user_Pass"] = decryptIt($row["user_Pass"]);
        $output["user_Email"] = $row["user_Email"];
        $output["user_status"] = $row["user_status"];

    }
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

or it's might be the cause of problem is the design template?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue reading HTTP request body from a JSON POST in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047870/issue-reading-http-request-body-from-a-json-post-in-php)

Comment: Could you narrow down the code here to one specific action/function that isn't working?  That's a lot to go through when there's probably one primary issue.

Comment: @PatrickQ ok sir. i already edit my question

Comment: Have you used your browser's network inspector to view the raw request and response?

Comment: @PatrickQ itried it but im not sure if im right , is that the tab near at console and source

Comment: @RhalpDarrenCabrera It should say "Network" or something along those lines (depending on your browser).  Click on the specific request related to this and view the response (probably towards the bottom).

Comment: @PatrickQ heres the image https://imgur.com/FfUKk4j

Comment: That's the delete request, not the fetch_single request.  Also, you need to click over to the Response tab in there to see the response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190526/discussion-between-rhalp-darren-cabrera-and-patrick-q).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solve this issue, in my requested php file i change my `$_POST`  to `$_REQUEST` if your data in ajax look like

```
data:{user_ID:user_ID}
```

or

```
data: "fname="+fname+"&lname="+lname
```

this might work for you, then if your data look like this `data:new FormData(this)` maybe you should use this type

```
 data:{user_ID:user_ID}
```

to work the request and execute your sql.

---

but the best solution i got is change your

> method:"POST"
>
> to
>
> type:"POST"

to solve this problem.

---

if your data.success_variable is undefined add

```
header('Content-type:  application/json.');
```

to your requested php file.

[image]

Related topic:
[ppumkin5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29034314/3903073) answer to
[JQuery Ajax is sending GET instead of POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195883/jquery-ajax-is-sending-get-instead-of-post)